# after par(fig), mtext is slightly off

Tags: r

I am creating a subplot with a function I called [smallPlot](https://github.com/brry/berryFunctions/blob/master/R/smallPlot.R#L125). It sets `par(fig)` to a subregion of the graph (or figure, for multipanel plots). However, after resetting the parameters, `mtext` is slightly off. Any idea, why this is happening?

```
dev.off()
plot(1:10)
mtext("hello", adj=1, col=2)            # written as expected
op4 <- par(fig=c(0.1,0.8,0.3,0.8), new=TRUE)   
par(op4)
mtext("hello ", adj=1, col=3)           # right spot
par(fig=c(0.1,0.8,0.3,0.8), new=TRUE)
plot(rnorm(400), type="l")
par(op4)
mtext("hello ", adj=1, col=4)           # too far left
```

Edit: the original question was different, but easily solved. Here it is for reference:

```
dev.off()
op1 <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
plot(1:10)
abline(h=2, col=2)                      # drawn

par(fig=c(0.1,0.8,0.3,0.8), new=TRUE)
plot(rnorm(400), type="l")
par(op1)
abline(h=4, col=4)                      # not drawn!
axis(4)
```

Answer: `op1$usr` is 0,1,0,1 per default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

op4 does not have a usr element. After the small inset plot, usr is changed. To reset, something like this can be used:

```
dev.off()
plot(1:10)
usr <- par("usr")
op4 <- par(fig=c(0.1,0.8,0.3,0.8), new=TRUE)
plot(rnorm(400), type="l")
par(op4)
par(usr=usr)
mtext("hello", adj=1, col=4); mtext("hello", adj=0, col=4)
```