# after par(fig), text in margins is not written

Tags: r, plot

After setting graphical parameters with `par(fig)` and resetting them with the original parameters, text in the margins of plots is not written.
Only after another low level command *inside* the plotting region is performed will it work again. Here's an example:

```
dev.off()
plot(1:10)
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)  
mtext("hello", adj=1, col=2)           # written as expected
par(fig=c(0.1,0.6,0.5,0.8), new=TRUE)  
par(op)
mtext("hello ", adj=1, col=3)          # not written
mtext("hello ", adj=1, col=3, line=-1) # works inside plot region
mtext("hello ", adj=1, col=3)          # still not written
text(50,20,"") # or abline             # do something inside plot region
mtext("hello         ", adj=1, col=3)  # now it works!
```

This may be related to another question I posted under [after par(fig), mtext is slightly off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392691/after-parfig-mtext-is-slightly-off).

Besides `mtext`, `axis` also does not work. Besides `text/abline/points`, `title(main="dummy")` also solves the problem.

Could this be an R bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I suspect `par(op)` starts a new plot. Replace `par(op)` with `par(fig = op$fig, new = TRUE)` and it works as expected.

Comment: Now that is interesting! `par(fig=op$fig)` suffices without `new`, btw.. That does not explain why it works in the plotting region but not in the margin, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By trial and error, it comes down to `par(mfg=c(1, 1, 1, 1))`.

```
plot(1:10)
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)  
mtext("hello", adj=1, col=2)           # written as expected
par(op[names(op) == "mfg"])
mtext("bye ", adj=1, col=3)            # not written
mtext("hello ", adj=1, col=3, line=-1) # works inside plot region

plot(1:10)
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)  
mtext("hello", adj=1, col=2)           # written as expected
par(op[names(op) != "mfg"])
mtext("bye ", adj=1, col=3)            # written as expected
mtext("hello ", adj=1, col=3, line=-1) # works inside plot region
```

It's not clear to me why setting the figure to be plotted next should disable printing text in the margin (but not in the figure), and since `mtext` is implemented in C, it would take some effort to work it out.